# joining table data by id

Tags: sql, join

**node**

```
id title content type
47 test  foobar  1
```

**type**

```
id name
1  blog
```

**output**

```
id title content type
47 test  foobar  blog
```

using the following query doesn't seem to be working...

```
 SELECT a.id, a.title, a.content, a.type
        FROM node a
        WHERE a.id = '. $id .'
        JOIN type b
        ON 
            a.type = b.id
```

how should I write this query to get the output I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there. You only need to place the `WHERE` condition last

```
    SELECT a.id, a.title, a.content, a.type
    FROM   node a
           JOIN type b ON a.type = b.id
    WHERE  a.id = '. $id .'
```

One remark and a personal preference, but I'd like to explicitly indicate the `JOIN` type to remove any doubts for people maintaining the code.

```
    SELECT a.id, a.title, a.content, a.type
    FROM   node a
           INNER JOIN type b ON a.type = b.id
    WHERE  a.id = '. $id .'
```

Comment: awesome that worked! I had to use `SELECT a.id, a.title, a.content, b.name` to get `blog` in my result set though.. is that a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.id,A.title,A.content,B.name as type
FROM node A,type B
WHERE A.id=B.id
  AND A.id='. $id .';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.content, b.name as `type`
FROM node a
INNER JOIN type b
ON a.type = b.id
WHERE a.id = '. $id .'
```